# sendgrid-php can't find class

Tags: php, sendgrid

I'm trying to send an email using sendgrid's php solution, following the instructions on the [github page](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) to install sans composer.  But PHP is throwing a

> ...Class 'SendGrid\Email' not found...

error.  Here's what I've got:

```
require("sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");
$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, $fromemail);
$subject = "archive shared with you";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $toemail);
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", $fromname . ' would like to ...  Visit your  page to see it. https://www.....com/login.php');
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->headers();
echo $response->body();
```

It has no problem loading the sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php file.

Comment: And did you include the `lib/helpers/mail.php` too? It has the only `Mail` class I could find under namespace `SendGrid`

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  When I add `require("sendgrid-php/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php");` I get the same error.

Comment: Ok, so you installed without composer and downloaded the zip package right?

Comment: correct.  looking at github I over loooked the php-HTTP-Client dependency.  Now trying to get that going without composer.

Comment: yep, that fixed it.  bonehead move to no include dependencies.